# Using @extend with Zurb Foundation and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use Foundation with Rails.

I have the foundation-rails gem installed and all configured, and I have no problem using Foundation classes in my markup. However, I'm trying to use @extend in my stylesheets, and it's not working. This is the my complete connections.scss file

```
.btn {
    @extend .button
}
```

There is an error in my logs:

```
WARNING on line 3 of <snipped>/connections.scss: ".btn" failed to @extend ".button".
The selector ".button" was not found.
```

I'm guessing I'm just missing an @import or something, but not really sure. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't RTFM very well.

I made my `application.scss` look like this:

```
 /*
  *= require_self
  *= require foundation_and_overrides
  */
  @import 'foundation_and_overrides';
  @import '*';
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't a very good solution because it's really slow. Previously my views rendered in ~50ms (in development.) Using @import it's ~2500ms. :(